# PHP - Operaciones con fechas y horas

Tags: php

Tengo 2 campos de texto para cada día de la semana donde se ingresa el horario de apertura y cierre de una tienda. Necesito mostrar en el front-end, calculando la hora actual, si la tienda está abierta, cerrada, si está a 30 minutos por abrir o si está a 30 minutos por cerrar.

Es un shortcode para Wordpres

´´´

```
// Shortcode Horarios Tienda
function horarios_tienda() {
    ob_start();
    $var = date("w");
    switch($var) {
    case 0: $dia = "domingo";
    break;
    case 1: $dia = "lunes";
    break;
    case 2: $dia = "martes";
    break;
    case 3: $dia = "miercoles";
    break;
    case 4: $dia = "jueves";
    break;
    case 5: $dia = "viernes";
    break;
    case 6: $dia = "sabado";
    break;
    }
    $product_cat_object = get_queried_object();

    $hora_actual = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
    $abre = get_field('apertura_' . $dia, 'product_cat_' . $product_cat_object->term_id);
    $cierra = get_field('cierre_' . $dia, 'product_cat_' . $product_cat_object->term_id);   

    if ($abre > $hora_actual || $cierra < $hora_actual) {
        echo "<span class=''>Abierto</span><br>";
    }
    if ($abre < $hora_actual || $cierra > $hora_actual) {
        echo "<span class=''>Cerrado</span><br>";
    } else {
        echo "<span class=''>Cerrado</span><br>";
    }


    return ob_get_clean();

}
add_shortcode( 'horarioTienda', 'horarios_tienda' );
```

´´´
Soy nuevo en PHP, agradecería muchísimo la ayuda.

Saludo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué hace el código actualmente?

Comment: No estaría funcionando. Indica que está "abierto" cuando debería indicar "cerrado" ya que la variable $abre tiene como valor '10:00'.

Comment: ¿Probaste los datos? No estoy seguro de que en `$hora_actual` estés obteniendo solamente la hora, sino la fecha completa. Haz `echo` de cada variable que usas en las comparaciones para verificar sus valores reales.

Comment: Está obteniendo la fecha también (2019-11-04 09:04:14). Debería formatearla así? $hora_actual = date( 'H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );

Comment: tampoco funciona. Lo que se me ocurre es convertir la hora a un entero. Tendrá algo que ver

Comment: No tienes que complicarte tanto, si quieres solamente la hora puedes hacer esto: `$hora_actual=date("H:i");` cuando sean las 10 de la mañana, el valor será `10:00` y cuando sean las 10 de la noche el valor será `22:00`. Prueba el valor de `$abre` y `$cierra`, dado que son datos que dependen de tu entorno no puedo comprobarlos. Si los valores son correctos, debería funcionar así.

Comment: Muchas gracias! fuiste de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si en `$abre` y `$cierra` hay datos como estos:

```
10:OO  #diez de la mañana
22:00  #diez de la noche
```

Tienes que extraer únicamente la hora actual, mediante el parámetro de formato `H:i`

```
$hora_actual=date("H:i");
```

Haciendo eso, podrás comparar los valores sin problemas. Ahora mismo no te está funcionando porque obtienes también día-mes-año para compararlo con un valor que es únicamente la hora.